# How to reset svg scaling and fit to screen for random but large maps/datasets with different orientations

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I need to rescale SVG elements to fit screens but since datasets will be random and of different orientations... I can't hard code to scale tree chart to fit into the screen after end user's zoomed in/out of it.

Here is an example of d3 tree chart - http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

Now I can using mouse zoom and move it to exactly middle of the screen as shown in picture below and get `SCALE + TRANSLATE` values, and hard code them within reset button...

[image]

**BUT** I will have random datasets so I can't hard code these values as I can't predict future.

**Question**

How can I ***using code*** figure out the scale and translate values of a random d3 tree chart generated using a random large dataset to `fit + scale` the `SVG > g` to centre of parent "`SVG`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the dataset is loaded, you can use getBBox() and transform it as follows: (I assume you would most likely want to have a fixed height value and let the width float accordingly).

```js
function fit()
{
 var bb=myChartG.getBBox()
 var bbx=bb.x
 var bby=bb.y
 var bbw=bb.width
 var bbh=bb.height
 //---center of graph---
 var cx=bbx+.5*bbw
 var cy=bby+.5*bbh
    //---create scale: ratio of desired width vs current width--
 var width=390 //---desired width (or height)
 var scale=width/bbw //--if height use myHeight/bbh--
 //---where to move it center of my pane---
 var targetX=200
 var targetY=200
 //---move its center to target x,y ---
 var transX=(-cx)*scale + targetX
 var transY=(-cy)*scale + targetY
 myChartG.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")scale("+scale+" "+scale+")")

 
}
```

Comment: Hi Francis, I tried it with one of the dataset and after some adjustments - it works, thanks